# How to make jni.h file for calling a c file from Java

Tags: java, java-native-interface

I am trying to follow this tutorial https://gist.github.com/DmitrySoshnikov/8b1599a5197b5469c8cc07025f600fdb for simply calling a c file from Java on mac.
I have successfully build my JNIExample.java and compiled it. I also made the JNIExample.h file as well.
But when I follow the 5th step: `gcc -I"$JAVA_HOME/include" -I"$JAVA_HOME/include/darwin/" -o libjniexample.jnilib -shared JNIExample.c` I receive this error:

```
JNIExample.c:2:10: fatal error: 'jni.h' file not found
#include <jni.h>
         ^~~~~~~
1 error generated.
```

Do you know how can I generate this file and solve this error?

My environment is mac and I have this files in my folder:

```
(base) MacBook-Pro-7:JNI-C++ Home$ ls
JNIExample.c        JNIExample.h
JNIExample.class    JNIExample.java
```

Comment: Is your `JAVA_HOME` variable set? The jni.h file is included with the JDK.

Comment: Hi, thanks. I found it
This is the path in my mac:
/Library/Java/JavaVirtualMachines/jdk1.8.0_151.jdk/Contents/Home/include

Answer (score 1):

`jni.h` is in $JAVA_HOME/include.

But it will fail, too, as jni.h references `jni_md.h` for *m*achine-*d*ependent features.
So you will have to add $JAVA_HOME/include/(linux|win32) to the include paths. (I'm not sure for MacOS)

Comment: It's the same approach on MacOS. For example, to add jni_md.h, I had to put $JAVA_HOME/include/darwin.